# Mongoose, referring to objects in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In case you have next data structure:

```
const branchSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
const Company = mongoose.model('Company', mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  branches: [branchSchema]
}));
```

How would you tell mongoose to use model from `Company`'s `branches` array during population?

```
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  branch: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Company.branches'}
}));
```

Comment: Do you want to access all of the branches in the Company model or just a certain one based on some criteria?

Comment: I need just one branch, based on the `_id` of branch stored in the `Item` entity.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the behavior you want, you could create a separate Branch model and then your Item model would look like this:

```
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  branch: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Branch'}
}));
```

Your Company schema would also look like this:

```
const branchSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
const Company = mongoose.model('Company', mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  branches: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Branch'}]
}));
```

Then in order to get the information related to branches when you perform a find you would use [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).